OnBase workflow automation
Has anyone ever tried to automate the OnBase process workflow?

Adding workflow tasks
Replace a workflow
Add or Modify Work view class, life cycle,
add unity script is mostly what we do.

This is the process we currently follow to actually deploy the changes.

We generate the OnBase export package in our OnBase studio and then import the package into a customer OnBase studio environment.
All the export packages have a decision file, and the process will decide if it wants to Replace/Create action.
Once we import the package and load decision file, it has run through a Verification process. Once the verification is complete, OnBase is ready to perform the import.

But this process takes a lot of person hours if we had to do the import process for a certain number of customers during after-hours every release.
I have tried tools like test complete trial, but I am not convinced if that is the product to automate the process of workflow.
